# Sending a link in an email to open an XPage in Notes Client

Tags: email, hyperlink, xpages

I have formated alink in an email to open a specific document in a web browser and that works fine. I also want to  include a link to open the document in the Notes Client. The link that I created looks like this:

notes://Development@MyOrg/__87257C6E007EC888.nsf/xpWFSDemoInput.xsp?action=OpenDocument&form=frmWFSAuthBasic&documentId=B2C4ACB0BC85F02B87257C7F00729796

the notes mail does not recognize this as a valid link and of course other mail systems would not know how to handle it either. Is there a way to format a link that would start Notes and connect to the correct server (In this case assuming it is called Development) using the users connection documents.

Comment: Try removing the @MyOrg part from the link and just use the server name.

Comment: Right but it is still ugly. I want to add it to the rich text body as an action rather than the big long string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are just looking to add a "friendly" link you need to send an HTML email. Plain text till not work.

```
<a href= 'linkhere'>Click here for link</a>
```

I am using Notes9/Domino9 so I am using the mailto action. if you need to be compatible with Domino 8.5 you will need to use a script to send your email and have it formatted as HTML.

Answer (score 3):

The best option is to associate the XPage with a form in the form's properties. Then you can use a classic looking link:
Notes://server/file.nsf/view/unid

View can be 0
When using a sorted view you can use the key instead of the unid

Also compose your body as mime, then you can use a href and put any content as visible text

To make MIME creation easier, use an XSnippet. there is a [bean version](http://openntf.org/XSnippets.nsf/snippet.xsp?id=emailbean-send-dominodocument-html-emails-cw-embedded-images-attachments-custom-headerfooter) or a [standard SSJS implementation](http://openntf.org/s/create-html-mails-in-ssjs-using-mime), so it is quite easy to do.